# Access map controls like OverviewMapControl or MapTypeControl

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The documentation indicates that there is a google.maps.Map.controls property that stores information about the controls added to the map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map

But accessing that property you get an MVCArray that has just has what looks like empty entries. Is there any way to get a hold of the objects for things like the overviewmapcontrol and maptypecontrol, so that we can more easily customize them?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for map options? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions If you are looking for a way to create custom controls, you can create your own buttons and bind events like `map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId['TERRAIN']);` to them.

Comment: There is no implemented way to access the built-in controls for a modification(except their position). The controls-property only provides access to the custom controls.

Comment: ok, that answers my question, yes I was trying to get at the objects for the built in controls